# DNA synthesis in nucleus

Tags: dna, dna-replication

I read somewhere that according to a research, I don't remember what the date was, that our cells stop synthesising DNA around noon and restart it around the sunset. The research told that it was actually a survival benefit for cells when ozone was not formed so that the DNA does not get damaged. Would somebody like to guess how our cells know when to do so and if it is a protection against present ozone depletion due to CFCs?